# Python: How to create a Trigonometric functions as in 4x4 Matrix, and can do matrix calculation with other matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, calculation, dot

# Use math and NUMPY function#

"mport math" and "import numpy as np"

Then I name 3 matrix as A B C

"A=np.array([ [1,0,0,0], [0,cos(2Θ)^2+cos(Φ)sin(2Θ],(1-cos(Φ))sin(2Θ)cos(2Θ),-sin(Φ)cos(Θ)], [0,(1-cos(Φ))sin(2Θ)cos(2Θ), sin(2Θ)^2+cos(Φ)cos(2Θ)^2, sin(Φ)cos(2Θ)] [0,sin(Φ)sin(2Θ), -sin(Φ)cos(2Θ), cos(Φ)]  )]

#this one should be right# "  B=np.array([ [0.5,-0.5,0,0], [-0.5,0.5,0,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0])] "

#this one should be right#   "C=np.array([ [1], [1], [0], [0] )]"

#this one should be in a wrong coding or missing some import function#
IF I want to do it togather
"result = np.dot(np.dot(A, B), C) print(result)"

It comes to
File "<ipython-input-51-94a4c36d06a9>", line 5
[0,cos(2Θ)^2+cos(Φ)sin(2Θ],(1-cos(Φ))sin(2Θ)cos(2Θ),-sin(Φ)cos(Θ)],
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

---

Comment: Did you just copy-paste the formula into your file and execute it with python? You need to parse your formula into valid Python code!!! For example `cos(2Θ)` is not valid. What is `Θ`? You should use `*` for multiplications.

Comment: `cos(Φ)sin(2Θ]`, `sin(Φ)cos(Θ)` are other examples of bad syntax.  It is hard write and use python code without having actually read a basic python text.